# Обновление slash-команд

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, disnake

Пытаюсь сделать бота с слэш-командой, где сама слэш-команда должна постоянно обновляться. Вот пример кода:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='посещаемость', description='Позволяет посмотреть, кто был на занятиях, в какое время, и сколько находился на них')
async def pos(inter: disnake.CommandInteraction, date:str=commands.Param(name='дата', description='Дата посещаемости', choices=[dt for dt in list(load(open('data/dates.json','r')).keys())])):
    await inter.response.send_message(date)
```

`[dt for dt in list(load(open('data/dates.json','r')).keys())]` - это список с ключами массива, который будет постоянно изменяться, но программа читает его при своём запуске, и больше не обновляет слэш-команду. (библиотека disnake)

**Возможно ли как-то обновлять слэш-команды в запущенном коде, или поставить их автообновление?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про [`autocomplete`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/slash_commands.html#autocompleters)-параметр у [`commands.Param`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api/app_commands.html#disnake.ext.commands.Param)

По первой ссылке есть пример из документации. Вам по сути нужно реализовать функцию, которая будет возвращать актуальный список параметров:

```py
async def autocomplete_func(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, user_input: str):
    with open('data/dates.json','r') as file:
        return list(load(file).keys())

@bot.slash_command()
async def example(
    inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction,
    param: str = commands.Param(autocomplete=autocomplete_func)
):
    ...
```